# Php xml Parsing efficiency

Tags: php, xml

I am pretty new to php and I understand this code is pieced together to work or at least feels that way, i know there is room for improvement. I am working with a very large XML file and am in need of getting a specific value from the file to fill in a block in my table. 
The xml essentially looks like this.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
  <Tasks>
   <Task>
   <UID>1234</UID>
   </Task>
  </Tasks>
  <Assignments>
   <Assignment>
    <TaskID>1234</TaskID>
    <ResourceID>1111</ResourceID>
   </Assignment>
  </Assignments>
  <Resources>
   <Resource>
    <UID>1111</UID>
    <Name>HELLO WORLD</UID>
   <Resource>
  </Resources>
 </Project>
```

Now Given the Task ID I need to look up in the XML the Assignment/Assignments associated with that task and get the Name of the resource. This file is very large and has many assignments with the code I am using only a portion of my table loads.
Here is my php.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$xml=simplexml_load_file("FILELOCATION.xml");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('project', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/project');
$tasks = $xml->Tasks;

function FindResource($strTaskID,$xml)
{

  $newPath = $xml->xpath("//project:Assignments/project:Assignment[project:TaskUID='$strTaskID']/project:ResourceUID");
 $resourceUID=(string)$newPath[0];
  if(!empty($resourceUID)&& (int)$resourceUID >0 )
  {
    $count =0;

   foreach ($newPath as $rUID)
   {
     if($count>0)
   {
         echo(", ");
    }
     $resource= $xml->xpath("//project:Resources/project:Resource[project:UID='$rUID']/project:Name");
     $resourceName = (string)$resource[0];

     echo($resourceName);
     $count++;
   }
  }
}

?>
```

And my html/php code that builds the table

```
<body>
            <table>
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                    <td>Task</td>
                                    <td>Resource</td>
                                    <td>Days</td>
                                    <td>Start</td>
                                    <td>End</td>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
<?php foreach ($tasks->Task as $value){ ?>
                    <tr>
                <td><span style="padding-left: <?php echo $value->OutlineLevel * 13; ?>px;"><?php echo $value->Name; ?></span></td>
                <td><?php echo FindResource($value->UID,$xml);?></td>
                <td class="duration"><?php echo FindDuration($value->Duration); ?></td>
                <td class="date"><?php echo OutputTime($value->Start);?></td>
                <td class="date"><?php echo OutputTime($value->Finish);?></td>
                    </tr>
<?php } ?>      </tbody>
                </table>
```

I have tried using xmlReader however, I was not able to get that to work. This works but I know is not efficient. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Under what assumptions do you believe this code is inefficient? You may be looking for the [code golf stack exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thought there might be a better way then using simplexml_load_file() and passing the xml to the function. I am having trouble loading the entire page, and thought it was maybe due to the size of the xml.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for now. Instead of passing in the XML and using xpath to get to the elements I needed, I broke the XML down into smaller pieces and worked with them individually. This gave me an idea in the future if need be to set up a key/value pair ahead of time as the assignments link tasks to resources. Being new to php this worked and loaded my web page faster than expected.

```
function FindResource($strTaskID,$xml)
{
    $assignment = $xml->Assignments;
    $assignmentArray = array();
    $resource = $xml->Resources;
    foreach($assignment->Assignment as $ass)
    {

       if((int)$as->TaskUID == (int)$strTaskID)
       {
            if((int)$as->ResourceUID >0)
            {
               $assignmentArray[]=$as->ResourceUID;
            }
       }
    }
    $count =0;
    foreach ($assignmentArray as $rUID)
    {
        if($count >0)
            echo(", ");
        foreach ($resource->Resource as $value)
        {
           if((int)$value->UID == (int)$rUID)
           {
              echo($value->Name);
              break;
           }
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
```